# Problems with libgtk after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

After upgrading ubuntu to 16.04, some graphic things started not working properly. For example, running `ccsm` from the command line will give me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ccsm", line 32, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: XRRGetMonitors
```

`font-manager` gives the following error :

```
Error: Importing pygtk and gtk modules failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: XRRGetMonitors)
```

What should I do ?

Graphic card : AMD Radeon R7 260X.

Output of `lspci -nn | grep VGA` :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XTX [Radeon R7 260X/360] [1002:6658]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently, and traced it to an incompatible copy of `libXrandr.so.2`

On the machine with the problem:

```
[20:45:36] [shane@ShanePC:~]$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 | grep -i randr
        libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fc9133be000)
[20:45:43] [shane@ShanePC:~]$
```

On a machine without the problem:

```
[21:07:46] [shane@Xion:~]$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 | grep -i randr
        libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f1542b7b000)
[21:07:51] [shane@Xion:~]$
```

Removing the stray library from `/usr/local/lib/` (which was from 2014) resolved the problem in my instance.

The correct library is from the `libxrandr2` package, so reinstalling that may also assist if `ldd` has it pointing to the right place.

Comment: Could you check that, please ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/16927090/

Comment: After loads of researches, I finally got it working, by deleting the file which was in `/usr/local/lib`, however, I had to delete `/usr/local/lib/libXinerama.so.1` beforehand

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are missing the libgtk2.0-0:amd64 package

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:amd64
```

I verified this by finding the file on my system and running

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

my hunch is that you will have more missing libs because some part of installation didn't work right. It might be worth running these commands to ensure you have all packages you need.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist upgrade
```

Edit:

it looks like you might have a corrupted version of that file 
you could try reinstalling that package

```
  sudo apt-get purge libgtk2.0-0:amd64
  sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:amd64
```

Comment: I am not missing it... apt-get install outputs this: `libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version`. I will try the dist upgrade

Comment: sorry , didn't notice that, i've added reinstall instructions

Comment: I had tried these too. The first command doesn't work (dependency issue), so I tried with `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgtk2.0-0 `, and reinstalling, but issue still there

Comment: I'll try this removal! I have a similar problem.

Comment: This libgtk2.0-0 was already installed , reinstalled and it worked.

Also updated the ubuntu -desktop and had reinstalled everything related to xorg.

Comment: sometimes packages go odd, i find this happens on systems that have been upgraded a lot, doing a purge and install  can remove bits of cruft left behind when a package jumps several versions or meets an unexpected version of a library. glad its sorted for you :)